# Run JavaScript from PHP if statement

Tags: javascript, php

so I saw a few similar questions like this but none worked for me so I thought I might as well ask. So I'm trying to make a popup load if the member's ID isn't in a database. I have all the PHP and SQL working for the database but I'm struggling to run the function for the JavaScript. 
I tried

```
if (condition){ 
   my database code;
  }else{
     my database code;
     echo "function()"
  }
```

I also tried

```
if (condition){ 
   my database code;
  }else{
     my database code;
     echo "<script type="text/javascript">function();</script>"
  }
```

but that still didn't work? I really want this on my website so if someone knows another way that would be **AWESOME** :) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not quoting your string correctly. Maybe this works for you: `echo "<script>function();</script>";`. If not you have to provide a more complete example.

Comment: It would be cleaner if you made a PHP variable like say $is_member and stored that in a JavaScript variable, so you didn't have to sprinkle JavaScript in your PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (condition){ 
   my database code;
} else {
   my database code;
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">function();</script>'
}
```

What was happening was that in `"<script type="text/javascript">function();</script>"` there were double quotes that weren't being escaped. Using singlequotes fixes this.

Comment: Hey so I know you answered my question, but I have another quick small one, so I'm trash at Javascript and I'm trying to run my function when the if statement is executed but it isn't working?? When I put the function onto a button it works perfectly but not when I just have `functionname()` would you like me to send you my code or should I make another question? This would help me so much :) thanks <3

Comment: It might be better to make another question @CharlieSimon Also, remember to upvote the answer ;)

Comment: @CharlieSimon Send the link to the question here

Answer (score 0):

Use this shortcut method:-

```
echo "<script>myFunction()</script>" ;
```